# Apple - No devices are registered in the Developer's account

Tags: apple-id, xcode

I've read a lot and even opened 2 tickets on Apple Support, but Apple is good at charging money for the air, so far not for the help. 
Here is the problem - I can't sign the app correctly as developer profile doesn't see a registered Mac.

Here is my full reply to the apple support:

1. Steps to reproduce the following:
   I open the xCode project. In Xcode preference & Accounts there is my profile Volodymyr Rudov-Tsymbalist set.  Go to the project settings, Signing & Capabilities mark "Automatic signing", choose my team and Bundle Identifier. Status returns me an error message: `Failed to create a provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website.`
   I go to the developer website: https://developer.apple.com/account/ , sign into the account and go to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles". Then to devices and see the Mac I registered to that account.
   image.png
   I go to Profiles section => generate profile, choose that option and receive "there are no devices available"
   [image: image 1]
   [image: picture 2]
   If I'm trying to register same Mac - I got an error that it is already registered.
2. Date: Wednesday 19 of Feb 2020 time: between 12:50 up to 23:00 we tried many times. Timezone - CET (Poland, +1 from UTC). Also it happens now, 21 February 2020 CET 9:42a.m.

3.there was a video

4. Volodymyr Rudov-Tsymbalist - the user.

5-6 Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)  & Safari v.13.0.5 (15608.5.11)

7. Xcode - v.11.3.1 (11C504)

Comment: Are you developing and trying to sign a MacOS application or an iOS application?

Comment: What type of Mac do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Problem sounds like you try to sign an adhoc app with your individual/company paid Apple Developer account. For this type of account adhoc distribution is for know devices (for example local test devices) only and need to known on which devices the signed app will be installed by signing.

From this devices the UDID will be crafted in the adhoc-profile. Your error message sounds like there are no devices linkend to your Xcode configuration so it can't create automatic a adhoc-profile that you need for singing and installation on a physical device.

> Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators

There you can pair with physical devices, if that is already the case I would like to advice you to look at your generic identifier of your app because it needs to be unique to pass the system and get ready for signing.

Comment: Problem resolved when plug an Iphone with the usb and launch code on it. Apple also replied that iOS xcode should be generated on iOS device first which should be registered.

Comment: Is there a way to upload for iOS without having a modern iOS device?  I'm getting this same error on my ionic (mostly web-based) project